# RabbitMQ .NET client async producer support?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Is async producer supported in RabbitMQ .NET? For example, await and async in .NET.

What about similar async support for Publisher Conformer?

Please provide links, or code example, if available.

Async Consumer is available:

- https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/pull/307
- https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/83
- https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/asynchronous-rabbitmq-consumers-in-net/